# JMeter test fragment use case to generate group name in jmeter result

Tags: jmeter

I have a Test Plan that contains the following:

**Test Fragment**

- Simple Controller with label "User Login"
- HTTP Sampler with label "User Login to website"

**ThreadGroup 1**

- Module Controller to call Test Fragment - Simple Controller with label "User Login"
- TG1 - Sampler 1

**ThreadGroup 1**

- Module Controller to call Test Fragment - Simple Controller with label "User Login"
- TG2 - Sampler 1

My problem is jmeter generate the following in jtl file

> User Login to website
>
> TG1 - Sampler 1
>
> TG2 - Sampler 1

I can't differentiate "User Login to website" call from each Thread Group.

How to configure jmeter to generate test result for each Thread Group despite using the same sampler from Test Fragment?
something like

> TG1 User Login to website
>
> TG2 User Login to website
>
> TG1 - Sampler 1
>
> TG2 - Sampler 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add to User Login Name request the thread group name by adding the following [__groovy](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) function:

```
${__groovy(ctx.getThreadGroup().getName())}
```

This will group user login per thread group in results

[image]